# How to rotate an item in SwiftUI and *then* lay out

Tags: swiftui, layout

I'd like to have vertical sliders. I know about `.rotationEffect()` but this rotates the item *after* it has been laid out, meaning it will overlap other elements in the layout as well as take up space which it does not visually use.

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
VStack {
  Text("Some long title")
  HStack {
    VerticalSlider()
    Slider()
    VerticalSlider()
  }
  Text("Some long footer")
}
```

I would expect the two vertical sliders not to overlap either label and only take enough width to draw the slider, and stretch to the available height of the `HStack`.

The regular (horizontal) slider should take most of the width of the `HStack`.

In other words, this would generate an "H" shape of sliders bound by the `HStack` and not interfering with other contents of the `VStack`.

Is this possible? Easily? I've seen methods for rotating text and setting its size, but that relies on asking it for its unconstrained size where `Slider`s always take all of the available room. Which is precisely what I want the vertical ones to do.

Comment: Here's an [example](https://github.com/john-mueller/SwiftUI-Examples/blob/master/SwiftUI-Examples/VSlider/VSlider.swift) of a vertical slider. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping it wouldn't need to be a complete re-implementation of the Slider control, which is what this appears to be. But... it's a complete implementation nicely wrapped, so may be what I end up using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard layout container, such as an `HStack`, only looks at the width and height of the items it is laying out. So in general, if a `View` with rotated content is to be shown inside a stack and you want the layout to work without having to set the width and height explicitly, it must have a natural width and height that incorporates the rotation effect.

For a vertical slider that consists of a regular `Slider` with rotation effect, one way to implement it would be to use a hidden placeholder that reserves the width and height needed, then show the `Slider` in an overlay over the placeholder.

You said the two vertical sliders should...

> only take enough width to draw the slider, and stretch to the available height of the HStack

A `Slider` is a particularly awkward example, because I don't think there is an easy way to get the width of a slider button. So I resorted to a hard-coded constant. However, the height is easy, you can just set `maxHeight: .infinity` on the placeholder:

```swift
struct VerticalSlider<V>: View where V : BinaryFloatingPoint, V.Stride : BinaryFloatingPoint {
    @Binding private var value: V
    private let bounds: ClosedRange<V>
    private let onEditingChanged: (Bool) -> Void
    private let sliderButtonSize: CGFloat = 27

    init(
        value: Binding<V>,
        in bounds: ClosedRange<V>,
        onEditingChanged: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = { _ in }
    ) {
        self._value = value
        self.bounds = bounds
        self.onEditingChanged = onEditingChanged
    }

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: sliderButtonSize)
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            .hidden()
            .overlay {
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    Slider(value: $value, in: bounds, onEditingChanged: onEditingChanged)
                        .frame(width: proxy.size.height)
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
                        .offset(
                            x: (proxy.size.width - proxy.size.height) / 2,
                            y: (proxy.size.height - proxy.size.width) / 2
                        )
                }
            }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var setting1 = 0.0
    @State private var setting2 = 0.0
    @State private var setting3 = 0.0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Some long title")
            HStack {
                VerticalSlider(value: $setting1, in: 0...10)
                Slider(value: $setting2, in: 0...10)
                VerticalSlider(value: $setting3, in: 0...10)
            }
            Text("Some long footer")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

If, on the other hand, all the items in the stack are being rotated, then a custom `Layout` might be a better approach. For example, a custom `Layout` would be a suitable way to lay out a collection of labels that all need to be shown at a particular angle, maybe sloped at 45 degrees.

Comment: Thanks! It is only the two sliders I need rotating. I wonder if a sensible width would in fact be the 'standard' 40pt minimum touch target size. Based on your screen capture that looks pretty tight at 27.

Comment: I measured the width of the standard button and came to 27pt without the shadow, but I agree that a safety margin is probably a good idea. Apple actually recommends 44 pt for a button in their [human interface guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/buttons#).

Comment: My memory was faulty. :-)  I tried it with 40 and it looked "spacious" as I would expect a default implementation to look. I have marked this as the correct answer as it is the most succinct I have seen and does actually use the Slider control, meaning, I think, that all current and future modifiers should work (subject to altering the fundamental characteristics of a Slider!)